# EntityManager remove() call not updating database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, entity

I have a basic Java project setup using JPA. I have classes which are annotated properly and can insert data into my PostgreSQL database without any trouble.

My question... and I may find that I need to add more detail here...

Is that I'm calling "em.remove(myObject)" where 'em' is an EntityManager. I can see the changes to the object when debugging but upon completion of the application my changes are not reflected in the database.

Will the call to .remove() update the database or do I also need to add a .flush() call? I've tried Googling this and must be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you reading the object from the database in the same transaction before you remove it?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the same transaction.

Comment: If it's not a detached instance then the remove call should work. If it's detached you'll need to make it managed first with `Object managed = em.merge(myObject);` and then call remove on `managed`.

Comment: if you are doing this inside a transaction are you submitting the transaction at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I also needed to define a cascade type.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Question question;
```

Comment: you should only add the cascade if you want the remove to remove the associated Question object as well. A cascade.REMOVE means that the remove on myObject will be executed on the Question object as well

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` call should remove the entity from the database. However, depending on your caching setup this may not happen immediately. And if you have some constraint that would be violated by the removal, then when it does try to update the database it will throw an exception and the removal will have failed. If you really need to guarantee that it happens or fails immediately, then yes, you will need to call `flush`.